# Sharing variables between different .tpl.php templates in drupal

Tags: templates, drupal, variables

I understand that to share variables between templates you have to use hook  preprocess.

I think I've got the hook preprocess bit ok.

I've got this in my theme's template php file.

function rootcandy_preprocess_views_view_fields__default(&$vars) {
$vars ['brian'] = 'hello from brian';

In views-view-fields--default.tpl.php I've got this:

print $brian ;

So it prints out "hello from brian". Hooray.

However I want to print out the header of my View - which is available in views-view.tpl.php but not in views-view-fields.

This code below looks promising but I don't understand why it doesn't result in my header being printed out in views-view-fields--default.tpl.php

function rootcandy_preprocess_views_view_fields__default(&$vars) 
{$vars['mytitle'] = $vars['view']->display[$vars['view']->current_display]->header['area'];
 }

I have of course got print $mytitle ; in views-view-fields--default.tpl.php

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of timing, when views-view-fields is parsing,  views-view has been parsed and you can't get his variables - They are not 'existing' anymore.

Use a function to generate the value and refer to that function in views-view and in views-view-fields, or create a module to produce this value and use it freely in any template.